# How to call phtml file from html in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, custom-template

I have included a custom button in checkout page on click of that I should get my **phtml** file as **popup**.

I have created a button in my custom module.

> \view\frontend\web\template\checkout\custom-checkout-page.html

Please help me in which path I should add my **phtml** file and how can I add it ?

Should I use any di?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. We create our **phtml**:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/html/my-custom.phtml

   ```
   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('My html is loaded') ?>
   <h3>successfully !</h3>
   ```
2. We instantiate our custom **phtml**:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml

   ```
   /* The Magento onepage code first, 
   then we add our myphtml var bellow the initial file code, 
   this file if you haven't it yet in your current theme, 
   you can copy it from :
   vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml*/


   ...

   <?php $myphtml = $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/my-custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var my_phtml = <?php echo json_encode($myphtml); ?>;
   </script>
   ```
3. We go to our **html** file then we create our popup and bind our **phtml** content

   for exmple: we add our popup in `shipping.html` file:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

   ```
   ...

   <div id="my-dialog-id" title="Information" data-bind="html:my_phtml" style="display:none;"/>
   <button data-bind="click: function(){
       jQuery(function() {
           jQuery('#my-dialog-id').dialog();
       });
   }">Show me my popup</button>
   ```

**Info:** make sure that you have well `code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` in your theme.

[image]

Comment: Like same how to load html file into phtml file https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313289/57334  Thanks @PЯINCƏ