# Magento 1 - How to apply custom popup message option to checkout courier selection?

Tags: popup, magento1.9.2.3, additional-information, radio-fields

In my website there is two courier service, customer can able to select the courier service as their wish. I am using the Matrix shipping rate.

[image]

Backend Code:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml**

courier option section:

```
<span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
<?php else: ?>

<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?> "<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>
```

And my HTML popup code:

https://paste.ofcode.org/qYJe3faagunkikwQph6UZP

HTML output :

[image]

How to apply HTML code into phtml file